# Java приложение, разрешение имен при помощи /etc/hosts

Tags: java, hosts

Мне нужно изменить свой сервис так, чтобы IP-адреса были не захардкожены в нем, а использовались имена из `/etc/hosts`. Вот часть кода приложения:

```
protected String getURI(Long block) {
        return "http://explorer:8080/api/block/claimdep/" + Long.toString(block);
    }
```

Это функция генерации адреса. Используется она так:

```
HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(getURI(nextBlock));

            try {
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

При запуске получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name may not be null
    at org.apache.http.HttpHost.<init>(HttpHost.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.determineTarget(AbstractHttpClient.java:586)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
    at service.BlockchainIndexer.run(BlockchainIndexer.java:58)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:9)
```

Почему адрес из hosts не зарезолвился? Он пигнуется по имени из hosts.

Comment: С Java всё в порядке. Я сейчас прописал у себя в hosts пару "127.0.0.1 example.com", `InetAddress.getByName("example.com")` возвращает правильное значение и `URL("http://example.com:8000").openConnection()` подключается. Возможно, проблема в Apache HttpClient.

Comment: Не мешает ли парсеру URI номер порта?

Comment: У меня ваш код работает с Apache HttpClient 4.5.6 (последняя сейчас версия) в Java 11 и Java 8u181. Однако вы не единственный, кто жалуется на такую проблему. Вот пример баг репорта с похожими симптомами, возникающими если сайт делает редирект: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1342

Судя по номерам строк в распечатке исключения вы пользуетесь какой-то более старой версией Apache HttpClient, скорее всего 4.0.x. Для начала попробуйте обновить её до последней. Так же вы не указали версию Java, в которой это запускаете.